# What is the difference between Bloomberg data feed (B-PIPE) and server api (SAPI)?

Tags: bloomberg

How are they different technologically and in terms of practical usage (e.g. different types of datasets available, etc)?

Researched around but can't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a high-level comparison, B-PIPE is just a data stream and SAPI is a traditional API. Both B-PIPE and SAPI give access to the same data that powers Bloomberg Terminal but that is effectively all that B-PIPE does whereas SAPI provides a more diverse interface for building out more robust applications. If all you need is the Bloomberg Terminal data stream, then B-PIPE is the more economical choice. However, if you need additional features then B-PIPE will not do but SAPI may suffice, depending on what you need.

UPDATED LINK: [Here is the documentation](https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/) for a more in-depth look at the two technologies.

Comment: Would you also happen to know how it’s all different from the other two data access methods: Bloomberg Data License (sftp/web service), and Bloomberg Platform API (another web service?) ?

Comment: The link in your answer is broken and I'm not sure what was on that link but [here](https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf) is the Bloomberg core developer guide from 2017. Please comment if you have a more recent version! thank you :)